# How can i parse an output like dictionary in python?

Tags: python, json

I have this code.

```
import json
 
with open('data5.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    data_2 = data.replace('[', ' ')
    data_3 = data_2.replace(']', ' ')
    print(data_3)
```

My variable data_3 is like that:

```
{"Manufacturer": "VMware, Inc.", "Model": "VMware7,1", "Name": "DC01"} ,  {"Index": "1", "IPAddress":  "192.168.1.240,fe80::350e:d28d:14a5:5cbb" }
```

I want to parse this. I want to get the value of Manufacturer or Model or Name. After parsing i will save them into the database. How can i do it?

```
import json
with open('data5.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = json.load(myfile)
    for i in data:
        print(data['Name'])
```

I tried this code for getting Name.
It gives me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.3\scratches\scratch_38.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(data['Name'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Why not use the `json` library: `data = json.load(myfile)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is json, so use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library from the stdlib:

```
import json
with open('data5.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = json.load(myfile)
```

No need to do any manual parsing.

Comment: but my data.5 json is like that                 [[{"Manufacturer": "VMware, Inc.", "Model": "VMware7,1", "Name": "DC01"}], [{"Index": "1", "IPAddress": ["192.168.1.240,fe80::350e:d28d:14a5:5cbb"]}]

Comment: So, with the mismatched []? Fix the generator.

Comment: I didnt understand sorry. Does my data5.json is a json or dictionary? and you mean that there are some mismatched [] ?

Comment: Your example has 4 opening [, but only 3 closing ]. Is that also true in your real data, or was that a mistake?

Comment: I have 3 outputs like :
[{'Manufacturer': 'VMware, Inc.', 'Model': 'VMware7,1', 'Name': 'DC01'}]
[{'Index': '1', 'IPAddress': ['192.168.1.240,fe80::350e:d28d:14a5:5cbb']}]
[{'Name': 'DC01', 'UserName': None}]

I tried to get them all in an array and this is the result. [[{'Manufacturer': 'VMware, Inc.', 'Model': 'VMware7,1', 'Name': 'DC01'}], [{'Index': '1', 'IPAddress': ['192.168.1.240,fe80::350e:d28d:14a5:5cbb']}], [{'Name': 'DC01', 'UserName': None}]]

IS it true?

Comment: Are you generating the JSON output by hand? Really, use a library.

Comment: No i didint generate the json output by my hand. I'm trying to parse after combining 3 different json outputs

Comment: So you are combining by hand. That sounds overly complicated. Just read the 3 separate json files.